# android Floating Action Button change view anchor dynamically

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I have a floating action button in the layout file of the fragment, Which signifies action to add data. I have used coordination layout of design support library and inside the `CoordinationLayout` I have put the linear layout holding 2 views in it and a floating action button.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dataLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
             />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewB"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"

                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/actionAddMembers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now initially the linear layout holding the 2 views would have `visibility=gone`. I want to bring the view in front when I click on floating action button. and I would like to anchor the FAB to the end of view A when the view appears on screen. I have seen that I can put the anchor in layout file and which makes my view static. I want to change this during run time when the view A appears on click of FAB . I couldnt find the any relavent methods in the `FLoatingActionButton` object to change the anchor dynamically . 
Kindly suggest me how can i achieve this task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the anchorId, retriving the `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams`.

You can use a code like this:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setAnchorId(xxxx);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: But what if the FAB is not directly in `CoordinatorLayout` and placed in `FrameLayout` for example?

Comment: How would this be in Kotlin?